# Crop multiple images with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have multiple images in different resolutions in a folder. With `ffmpeg` I create a video from all of these.

**My Execute**

`ffmpeg -framerate 1 -pattern_type glob -i "$tempPath/*.jpg" $tempPath/$videoFileName.mov`

What I get is a video from all of my images. This works well. But: Many of my images are skewed. So I think I need to crop them. Or is there a function like CSS `background-size: cover`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First, crop the images using ImageMagick tool `convert`, then create video out of them using `ffmpeg`.

From the [ImageMagick examples for crope](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/) using `convert`:

```
convert image.png -crop 40x30+90+60 crop.png
```